# How to compare different clusterings of the same data

Tags: clustering

If I have two groups of clusters of the same data (e.g. that were created using different modalities), what's a standard/established way of discovering interdependencies/relationships between the two clusterings?

Answer (score 1):

There are many measures for clustering similarity.  At least three different takes on the problem are available:

1) Similarity - produces a value between 1 (identical) and 0.  examples include [Rand Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index), [Normalized Mutual Information](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score.html) (NMI), [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).

2) Adjusted similarity measures allows you to compare the observed similarity score against the similarity of "random" clusterings.  examples include Adjusted Rand index, Adjusted NMI.  Several different choices for your definition of random clusterings are available, see [Impact of Random Models](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v18/17-039.html).

3) Element-centric approaches that reveal which elements contribute to the differences between clusterings.  see [On comparing clusterings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06136) or [Relational Flexibility](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.05523).

All of these approaches are implemented in the [CluSim python package](https://github.com/Hoosier-Clusters/clusim).

Answer (score 0):

Same as for comparing clusterings to labels.

Most of these measures (ARI, NMI etc.) are symmetric, and not at all limited to evaluating against a "ground truth".